# ¿Cómo usar librerias en react si no estan en npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Hola quiero usar una librería de js que se llama Glider.js aquí esta la documentación (https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/) esta libreria no esta disponible en npm, o no la he encontrado asi que he estado intentando usar react-helmet para poder importarla, este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
<Helmet>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1.7.7/glider.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1.7.7/glider.min.js" />
    <script src="./../Carrousel.js" />
</Helmet>
```

-Aqui este codigo esta tomando los respectivos links a los estilos css, y el archivo de js de la libreria y ademas estoy usando un archivo donde tengo todas las funciones necesarias para usar esta libreria, que tiene este codigo dentro:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   new Glider(document.querySelector('.carrousel__list'), {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: '.carrousel__indicators',
        arrows: {
            prev: '.carrousel__before',
            next: '.carrousel__next'
        },
    });
    
    new Glider(document.querySelector('#carrousel__list2'), {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: '#carrousel__indicators2',
        arrows: {
            prev: '#carrousel__before2',
            next: '#carrousel__next2'
        },
    });
    new Glider(document.querySelector('#carrousel__list3'), {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: '#carrousel__indicators3',
        arrows: {
            prev: '#carrousel__before3',
            next: '#carrousel__next3'
        },
    });
    new Glider(document.querySelector('#carrousel__list4'), {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: '#carrousel__indicators4',
        arrows: {
            prev: '#carrousel__before4',
            next: '#carrousel__next4'
        },
    });
});
```

Solo que no me reconoce la funcion de `new Glider`, ni pasa nada en la pagina

Comment: podrías importar la cdn directamente en el html y automáticamente tendrías el método `Glider` englobado en tu app

Comment: Solo tienes q descargar el archivo js y usar require.